# How to load list of images in R with saveHTML?

Tags: r, animation

Relatively new to R but very new to 'animation' in R

I have created the following list of 50 .png images in the following directory:

```
library(animation)
library(png)
path<-list.files("C:/Users/Justin/Pictures/dotimages",pattern='.png')
```

I have attempted to create an HTML version of the animation using this code and it comes up blank:

```
saveHTML({
   for(i in 1:length(path)) {readPNG(path[i],TRUE)
}
},img.name="test",interval=1,htmlfile="test.html")
```

I've looked at a few of the tutorials in 'animation' but haven't completely understood how to display these images consecutively in an .html file with this function.  Any help or direction appreciated.

Comment: If your target is HTML, then https://github.com/tdhock/animint might be interesting to try, but I tend to prefer using `convert` (from ImageMagick) or ffmpeg/avconv directly (i.e. on the command-line or shell/system call) to do the conversion to mp4 or animated gif over HTML animations.

Comment: The result of the expression first argument of `saveHTML` must produce a plot. So far, you only read the `png` files. See `?readPNG` and the examples to learn how to plot the value of `readPNG`.

Comment: When you do do your `plot` of the images make sure to add `asp=TRUE` to preserve the correct aspect ratio on the x&y axes. However, for what you're trying to do, something like `convert -delay 100 *.png animation.gif` seems more appropriate (if you have ImageMagick installed).

Comment: nicola - I've looked around at readPNG some more and have this below but the plot is blank:   
    saveHTML({
    for(i in path){
    tmp<-readPNG(i)
    plot(asp=TRUE)
    rasterImage(tmp)
    }
    },img.name="test",htmlfile="test.html")